# $Hom_R(R,-):Mod_R\to Mod_R$ is not strong isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

This is a problem from Rotman 5.37. I do not think I grasp the gist of the problem statement.

$R$ might not be a commutative ring here. A functor $F:\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ is strong isomorphism if there is a functor $G:\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{A}$ such that $GF=1_{\mathcal{A}},FG=1_{\mathcal{B}}$. Clearly $Hom_R(R,-):Mod_R\to Mod_R$ is naturally isomorphic to $1_{Mod_R}$ where $Mod_R$ is the right $R-$module category. Then $Hom_R(R,-)$ is not strong isomorphism. And it should be boring?

If $Hom_R(R,-)$ is strong isomorphism(note it is exact and the adjoint is also exact), then the adjoint of it should be $-\otimes R:Mod_R\to Mod_R$ as $R$ is $(R,R)$ bimodule. However, $R$ is flat as $(R,R)$ module which makes $-\otimes R= 1_{Mod_R}$ natural isomorphism. Apparently, that it is strong isomorphism from this.

1. Something is wrong with my understanding above.
2. I just concluded $Hom_R(R,-)=-\otimes R=1_{Mod_R}$. I do not think I grasped the gist of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about "strong isomorphisms" (which are usually just called isomorphisms of categories), you need to be careful to distinguish between (naturally) isomorphic objects and *equal* objects.

In particular, for instance, if $F$ is a strong isomorphism, then $F$ must be surjective on objects, since $FG=1_\mathcal{B}$ is surjective on objects.  This is not true of $F=Hom_R(R,-)$: not every module $M$ is equal to a module of the form $Hom_R(R,N)$.  Here by "equal" I mean equal in the most literal possible set-theoretic sense (equal underlying set and equal module operations), not just isomorphic.  For instance, by definition, any element of the underlying set of $Hom_R(R,N)$ is a function, so if you take a module $M$ whose underlying set has an element which is not a function, it cannot be equal to $Hom_R(R,N)$ for any module $N$.

Comment: Yes. I think the notation tricked me as I have never seen natural isomorphism notation but equality somewhere in the book.